# Проблема с паузой при вызове Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

В скрипте используется сторонний файл типа *.jar
Для его запуска используется файл bat, который вызывается следующим образом

```
from subprocess import Popen

p = Popen(gatlingdir + '\\bin\\gatling.bat -ro res', cwd = gatlingdir + '\\bin')
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

После выполнения сторонний файл выводит: "Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу..."

Можно ли это как-то обойти?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из документации https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen.communicate

```
# Если хотите что-то послать в stdin процесса, необходимо указать stdin=PIPE:
p = Popen(gatlingdir + '\\bin\\gatling.bat -ro res', cwd = gatlingdir + '\\bin', stdin=PIPE)
```

Оттуда же

```
# Необязательный аргумент input означает данные, которые будут посланы в дочерний процесс
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(input='1')
```